# Copying files based on modification date in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, cp

I want to copy the last three months' files from one directory to another directory, but I could find only listing the files by using the following command.

```
find . -mtime -90 -ls
```

How can I copy the files by using `-mtime`?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use the `-exec` option for `find`:

```
find . -mtime -90 -exec cp {} targetdir \;
```

`-exec` would copy every result returned by `find` to the specified directory (`targetdir` in the above example).

Comment: Well, I'm using the `zshell`. All my files disappeared. I used  the `mv` command.

Comment: if want move files during a period, use `find . -type f time_criteria -exec mv -t target_dir {} +`

Comment: @ YinchaoOnline: What determines the period? Is "time_criteria" literal? If not, what is the syntax/content?

Answer (score 16):

One can also select the exact date and time other than going back to a certain number of days:

```
cp  `find . -type f -newermt '18 sep 2016 20:05:00'` FOLDER
```

The above copies all the files in the directory that were created after 18 September 2016 20:05:00 to the `FOLDER` (three months before today :)

Be careful with the symbol for the find command. It is *not* this one: '

It is this, a backtick: `

Date selection is with this: '

If you have files with spaces, newlines, tabs, or wildcards in their names, you can use either of the solutions from Stéphane Chazelas. The first is for GNU, and the second is for GNU or some [BSDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution):

```
find . -type f -newermt '18 sep 2016 20:05:00' -exec cp -t FOLDER {} +
find . -type f -newermt '18 sep 2016 20:05:00' -exec sh -c 'cp "$@" FOLDER' sh {} +
```

Answer (score 7):

I would first store the list of files temporarily and use a loop.

```
find . -mtime -90 -ls >/tmp/copy.todo.txt
```

You can read the list, if it is not too big, with

```
for f in `cat /tmp/copy.todo.txt`;
do echo $f;
done
```

Note: the quotes around cat... are backticks, often in the upper left corner of the keyboard.

You can then replace the [echo](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) command with a copy command:

```
for f in `cat /tmp/copy.todo.txt`;
do cp $f /some/directory/
done
```

Comment: On my keyboard backticks are located to the upper right. Next to the question mark. (European/Nordic keyboard)

Answer (score 5):

Use this command:

```
for i in `ls -lrt | grep "jul" | awk '{print $9}' `; do cp $i* /some/folder/; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Example: select day 09/08/2017

```
ls -l
 -rw-rw-rw-    1    root     system          943   Aug   09   02:59  File

for j in `ls -l |awk '{ if ($7 == "09") print $9}'`
    do
        mv $j $Destination;
    done
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order (especially since it seems to use [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) and seems to presume something about the output from `ls` - for instance, would it work if the [locale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale_(computer_software)) was German?).

Answer (score 0):

```
cp $(ls -t1 | head -n -(fileno))) dest
```

**The** *fileno* represents the number of the current files to be copied