# How to copy all files added to a specific directory in the past 5 minutes?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, copy

I would like to know how to copy over files that were added to a specific directory in the past five **minutes**. The files are not necessarily created within the directory (i.e., may be copied over from a different directory). The files have a specific format which includes the date and time of creation, however I would prefer if the selection of the files is not dependent on the date/time stamp within the file name. How can this be done?

Comment: Why do you have this tagged `bash` if it is a question about `ksh`?

Comment: It has been removed @Two-BitAlchemist

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copying the files based on modification date in linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179643/copying-the-files-based-on-modification-date-in-linux)

Comment: You can just use a combination of unix find and cp for this. I don't think there's anything shell-specific about it anyway. I have never used ksh, so if this won't work for you for some reason, just say so.

Comment: Are files tagged as modified if they are moved from one directory to another? @Two-BitAlchemist

Comment: No, merely moving them will not update the _modified_ time but it will update the _change_ time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the functionality that I needed by using this code block:

```
# Fill date variables 
date '+%Y %m %d %H %M %S' | read in_Y in_m in_d in_H in_M in_S

# Decrease month count to account for first month being at index 0
((in_m=$in_m-1)) 

# Get current time in seconds since epoch
perl -e "use Time::Local; print timelocal($in_S,$in_M,$in_H,$in_d,$in_m,$in_Y), ;" | read cur_S

# Go back five minutes
((old_S=$cur_S-300))

# Change to required format
perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime);\
print scalar(strftime "%Y %m %d %H %M %S", localtime $ARGV[0]), "\n";' $old_S | read Y m d H M S

# Create temp file to act as time reference
touch -amt ${Y}${m}${d}${H}${M}.${S} ${tempFileDest}

cd $testSourceDir

# Find files created in past five minutes
find . -type f -newer temp -name $fileNameFormatTest -exec cp -pf {} $testDestDir \;
```

Thanks for the help!

Note: This is a work around for HP-UX which does not support the -amin, -cmin, -mmin options for the 'find' command.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the directory of a file does not update modified time or access time, but does update change time. You simply need to use the `-ctime` flag on find to catch this:

```
$ mkdir test
mkdir: created directory ‘test’
$ cd test
$ touch a
$ stat a
  File: ‘a’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 802h/2050d  Inode: 2117512     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/moriarty)   Gid: (  100/   users)
Access: 2015-02-13 10:24:16.777863605 -0600
Modify: 2015-02-13 10:24:16.777863605 -0600
Change: 2015-02-13 10:24:16.777863605 -0600
 Birth: -
$ mkdir b
mkdir: created directory ‘b’
$ mv a b
$ stat b/a
  File: ‘b/a’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 802h/2050d  Inode: 2117512     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/moriarty)   Gid: (  100/   users)
Access: 2015-02-13 10:24:16.777863605 -0600
Modify: 2015-02-13 10:24:16.777863605 -0600
Change: 2015-02-13 10:24:26.354530678 -0600
 Birth: -
$ find b -cmin -5
b
b/a
```

If you want find to ignore the directory just pass it a `-type f` meaning only files are to be considered.

```
$ find b -type f -cmin -5
b/a
```

Then you can use its `-exec` argument to pass it the cp command, which it will execute over every result. Use `-print` or just the bare command above (no `-exec`) to see what it is catching.

```
$ mkdir c
mkdir: created directory ‘c’
$ find b -type f -cmin -5 -exec cp '{}' c \;
$ ls c
a
```

#### Edit:

The only way I can think of to do this on a system like HP-UX that doesn't support `-cmin` is basically to create a temporary dummy file with a timestamp indicating the time you want (five minutes ago in your case) and compare against that. You can set the timestamp on a Unix file as you desire with [`touch -t`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?touch) and then use the `-newerc` argument to find to select files with a newer change time than the standard one you just made. I found [an online reference](http://docstore.mik.ua/manuals/hp-ux/en/B2355-60130/find.1.html) purporting to be a manual for HP-UX from around 2007 that indicates that it does support the `newer[xy]` syntax.

Comment: I am not getting the functionality that I expected. Does -ctime indicate time in days? Is there any specific option for minutes? I have tried -mmin and -cmin testing in the terminal, but both return "bad option".

Comment: GNU find has cmin (`-ctime n` is documented to mean n*24 hours ago) but there are different versions of find, so you may not have that.

Comment: Can you recommend some other way about handling this issue? It does not seem like cmin/mmin is available to me and I cannot use a fractional number for n when using ctime.

Comment: What OS are you using? It's been a while since I came across a find without `-cmin` and I'm having trouble determining which versions do and don't have it. Also, pull up `man find` and search for "cmin" -- you are sure your version of find _does not have this_ as opposed to you are reversing find's argument order or something? (It is picky about that.)

Comment: I am using HP-UX, which seems to be Hewlett Packard's proprietary Unix OS. I have accessed the man pages for find and I believe I am correct in saying that there is no support for "cmin".

Comment: It is indeed. I have edited my answer with my best idea to replace the missing `-cmin` functionality. I must admit I'm getting a bit far afield of my Unix capabilities here as I've never used either HP-UX or ksh.